# Including Partials, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm building my first ASP.NET MVC application and I am having some troubles with Partial Views.

If I, as an example, want to put a "Footer" as a Partial I create an "MVC View User Control" in "/Views/Shared/Footer.ascx". (I leave it empty for now)

What is the correct way for adding it to my Layout?

I have tried:

```
<%=Html.RenderPartial("Footer")%>
```

and:

```
<%=Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/Footer.ascx")%>
```

For each one I get an exception:

> "CS1502: The best overloaded method
>   match for
>   'System.IO.TextWriter.Write(char)' has
>   some invalid arguments"

What is the correct way to deal with partials in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In this case don't use the <%= syntax.  Just use the <% %> syntax.  Then the first form in your examples should work.

For more info, check here:
http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2008/08/partial-renderi.html

Answer (score 13):

Do what @BenScheirman said, and add a semi-colon at the end of your statement :)

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/Footer.ascx"); %>
```

Update: I guess VB doesn't require the semi-colon. So you would only need that if you are programming in C#.

Comment: The author of the question is most probably coding in VB.NET. Semi-colons are not a part of the VB.NET language.

Comment: I think the CS compiler error is a hint at C# being used here...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b66k5sz9(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Whoops, thanks for the catch Ricky.  (and no, I'm NOT programming in VB.NET)